# Cake: using relative urls

Tags: url, cakephp

My login redirect is being built with an absolute url but I need to use a relative url because my cakephp application is being served up through a proxy server.

The Router class has properties that effect the behavior of the url method (documentation link: 
http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerurl )

I think what I want to do is set the 'base' property to false, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Do I just specify

```
$this->base = false;
```

somewhere? (I tried doing this in the beforeFilter in the controller but it had no effect).

Update: Well, it's not the ideal solution but I can get the links to work through the proxy server by adding this line to paths.php:
define('FULL_BASE_URL','http://www.myexternaldomain.com');

and then I also had to set the security level to low in core.php.

But then this means that went I access the cake pages locally with 
http://localhostname/cake/users

I'll get redirected to the external url which is not what I would prefer.

Update:

Here is the output of a print_r($_SERVER) from my dev server:

Array ( [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200 [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200 [HTTP_HOST] => devdataload [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101028 CentOS/3.6-2.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.11 [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us,en;q=0.5 [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 [HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE] => 115 [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive [HTTP_REFERER] => http://devdataload/cakepf/users/login [HTTP_COOKIE] => CAKEPHP=ndhjfch0c1oq285ks4d2dfib90; ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3 [PATH] => /usr/bin:/bin [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
Apache/2.2.8 (CentOS) Server at devdataload Port 80
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.8 (CentOS) [SERVER_NAME] => devdataload [SERVER_ADDR] => 5.213.249.197 [SERVER_PORT] => 80 [REMOTE_ADDR] => 5.213.249.197 [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/cakepf/app/webroot/index.php [REMOTE_PORT] => 39979 [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => url=alerts [REDIRECT_URL] => /cakepf/app/webroot/alerts [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [QUERY_STRING] => url=alerts [REQUEST_URI] => /cakepf/alerts [SCRIPT_NAME] => /cakepf/app/webroot/index.php [PHP_SELF] => /cakepf/app/webroot/index.php [REQUEST_TIME] => 1299347553

Comment: See answer below. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though. Do you have a concrete example how you generate URLs, what you're getting and what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution isn't ideal but at least it's functional. In my production system I add this line into `paths.php`:

```
define('FULL_BASE_URL','http://<proxy server name>');
```

This ensures that all urls go through the proxy server.

In `dev/test` where I am only working locally, I comment that line out.

Answer (score 3):

Cake handles relative and absolute URLs just fine, as long as you **don't hardcode them**.
When specifying URLs you should always do so in terms of the targeted controller and action and let Cake figure out the actual URL.

An `array('controller' => 'foos', 'action' => 'bar')` will be translated dynamically to `/foo/bar`, `/project/cake/foo/bar` or whatever else is appropriate. If you need an absolute URL, set the appropriate parameter to `true`:

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'foos', 'action' => 'bar'), true)
→ http://example.com/foos/bar
```

Comment: It's not handling them fine for me. I haven't hardcoded them anywhere but when I try to access http://www.myexternaldomain.com/cake/alerts through the proxy server and I haven't logged in yet, it redirects me to http://mylocalserver/cake.

Comment: @opike Can you please give more details on your setup? Where *should* it redirect? What request do you receive (`print_r($_SERVER)`)? How is the AuthComponent configured? Any other helpful information?

Comment: The links exposed to the internet are http://www.<mydomain>.com/cakepftest/alerts. However www.<mydomain>.com is just a proxy and cake is actually running on a hostname called testdataload. If the user tries to access http://www.<mydomain>.com/cakepftest/alerts before they have logged in, they are redirected to http://testdataload/cakepftest. The AuthComponent seems to be configured fine; all behavior is as expected other than the redirect issue.